# VAlor máximo do listview1.scrollviewpos

Tags: listview

Bom dia,
a todos

Se alguém puder dar um help... Como saber o valor máximo do scroll do listview ( listview1.scrollviewpos ),
não estou conseguindo descobrir.

Obrigado,
Cassiano

Answer (score 0):

Use a função de API **GetScrollRange**.

`GetScrollRange(ListView.Handle,SB_VERT,Minimo,Maximo);`

Comment: Carlos, estou usando firemonkey não funcionou. já resolvi, enviei a resposta lá no grupo. obrigado pela ajuda.